# Unicode filenames not preserved on windows when downloading zip of gitlab repo

Tags: windows, gitlab, cyrillic, mojibake

I have a Gitlab repo where one of my files is named "инит.ћ". I created the repo on a Linux machine, and now I'm trying to download it from the Gitlab webpage onto a Windows machine.

This results in that specific filename getting mojibake'd into "-+-+-+-é.-¢".

When I use git to clone the repo, this doesn't happen, and the filename is preserved. And when I download the zip file on Linux, the filename is still preserved.

Is there any way to remedy this. I'm not even slightly familiar with how windows deals with filenames. So I don't think I can give much more useful info than that.

Comment: Does it work if you use another program, e.g. [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), to open the archive?

Comment: @AndrewMorton just did, that worked, i guess I'll have to inform people to use that, thank you

Comment: The zip software built into Windows is not the best there is...